# Using lr.stop_transaction() in LoadRunner 12.02 using Java over HTTP protocol

Tags: java, loadrunner

How to place lr.stop_transaction() in LoadRunner 12.02 using Java over HTTP protocol. I used the same and got compiler error "cannot find symbol". The Syntax is available in LoadRunner help tab but it's not working when used.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Is your Java over HTTP protocol script A C language script or a Java Language script?   Do your functions being with lr. or lr_?